# Is it possible to define metric spaces from pure topological concepts without the need to define a distance function?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Reading a book this question comes to my mind: would it be possible to define metric spaces using only topological concepts, without an explicit definition of a metric?

For example, can we say that all Hausdorff spaces are metric spaces?

Comment: You may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem) interesting

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba thank you very much. It seems that the concept of "metrizable" answer the question.

Comment: You're welcome. Particularly, pay attention to [Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is possible to define the class of *metrizable* spaces in purely topological terms. Indeed, there are many so-called metrization theorems that characterize the class of metrizable spaces topologically; here is a bundle of four of them.

> **Theorem.** The following are equivalent for a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$:
>
> 1. $X$ is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base.
> 2. $X$ is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-discrete base.
> 3. $X$ has open covers $\mathscr{G}_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ such that
>
>    - if $G_0,G_1\in\mathscr{G}_{n+1}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and $G_0\cap G_1\ne\varnothing$, then there is a $G_2\in\mathscr{G}_n$ such that $G_0\cup G_1\subseteq G_2$, and
>    - whenever $x\in U\in\tau$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $\bigcup\{G\in\mathscr{G}_n:x\in G\}\subseteq U$ for each $n\ge m$.
> 4. $X$ is a paracompact [Moore space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)).
> 5. $X$ is metrizable.

However, a *metric* space by definition comes equipped with a metric, and a metric space with more than one point always has more than one metric that generates the same topology. Thus, we don’t actually have a metric space until we specify the metric, even when we know that there is one that generates the desired topology. If a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ satisfies one of the four conditions above, there is a way to construct a metric on $X$ that generates the topology $\tau$, but there are many other metrics on $X$ that generate the same topology.

Comment: I understand, the answer is clear and very complete to know what I wanted to know. Thank you Brian.

Comment: @Masacroso: You’re welcome.

Comment: +1 for nice emphasis on distinction between "space for which a metric is assigned" and "space for which a metric can be assigned".

Comment: I misunderstood the question :) I like your answer by the way.

Comment: @OpenBall: I wondered if that might have been the case. Thanks!

Comment: such a great answer!!